# How to merge a variable title and link_to button in one button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, hyperlink

I'm new to rails/html and I'm struggling to combine a title which varies from 'outing' to 'outing' and the link_to function would take the user to the 'more details' information on that 'outing.

Both buttons are working as coded independently but would look much better in the carousel if combined but I can't figure how I would add the 'link_to' into the href OR how to add the <%= outing.date_title %> into the 'link_to' button.  Thanks !

```
                        <div class="carousel-caption caption-shadow-large">
                          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button"><%= outing.date_title %></a></p>
                          <div class="btn-group">
                            <%= link_to 'more details', outing, 
                               :class => "btn btn-default align-center" %>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: just to make sure, you want to make the link_to link to say "outing.date" instead of "more details"?

Comment: yep, that's correct !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can customize what to display in the link to by doing this

```
<div class="btn-group"> 
    <%= link_to(outing) do %> 
        <div class="btn btn-success" role="button">
            <%= outing.date_title %>
        </div> 
    <% end %> 
</div>
```

check: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Thanks Arop, that's close to what I needed but how would I add in the Bootstrap button code to format it like I have above with the :class button formatting?

Comment: you can put whatever you want inside the do statement, that is to say you can put the button tag inside that like 
" link_to ... do ... <button> ...</button> ... end "

Comment: Thanks Arop!  that is now working, this is the final code i used (note - i'm using bootstrap for formatting)                                 <div class="btn-group">
                               <%= link_to(outing) do %>
                                  <div  class="btn btn-success" role="button"><%= outing.date_title %>
                                  </div>
                               <% end %>
                              </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to outing, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <%= outing.date_title %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to combine some icons (like Font Awesome for example), you can do that like this:

```
<%= link_to outing, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <%= outing.date_title %>
<% end %>
```